# Delphi: Close all forms (except MainForm), but, ignore any OnCloseQuery dialogs

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Basically, I'm using a `TTimer` event to close all the open forms and bring the user back to the main form.
I could iterate through `Screen.Forms`:

```
for i := 0 to Screen.Formcount - 1 do
  Screen.Forms[i].close;
```

The problem is the `OnCloseQuery` events on some of those forms - they pop up `MessageDlg`'s which interrupt this process :(

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to 'hack' the 'OnCloseQuery' event of all the forms.
Also, when a MessageDlg pops up,  this can count as a 'new' form, which was not in the "close" loop before, so it has to be closed manually.

Comment: If they're interrupting the process for a reason, then they shouldn't be closed. If there's no reason for them to not to close then they shouldn't be interrupting the process (they shouldn't set 'CanClose').

Comment: The OnCloseQuery events frequently contain MessageDlgs saying "Are you sure you want to cancel this activity?" Yes / No
--I don't want to even offer them such a choice -- I want to close, without OnCloseQuery.

Comment: So you're asking the user if there's a reason for not to close. I would just be sure that there's a visual indication that there's an activity and leave the rest to the user. But maybe that's just me..

Comment: With respect, I think you're kinda begging the question - there are design reasons for what I'm trying to do.
After 10 minutes of inactivity, the user is 'logged out' (within the app) and brought back to the Login Screen. Basically, "Whatever forms you were busy with must be forced to close and forget about them". Not, "Oh, someone was busy with this form, are you sure you want to cancel, stranger?"

Comment: Seems like you need to refactor your app.  "Close handling logic" could be delegated to a single place that has all the information it needs. Much nicer than a global boolean hack.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a flag in your main form that your other forms would check before asking the user whether to proceed or not. Something like this:

unit1

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  public
    UnconditinalClose: Boolean;
  end;

..

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnconditinalClose := True;
end;
```

unit 2:

```
implementation

uses
  unit1;

procedure TForm2.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := unit1.Form1.UnconditinalClose;
  if not CanClose then
    // ask the user if he/she's sure he/she wants to close
end;
```

One other solution could be detaching `OnCloseQuery` event handlers of other forms. <strike>This would only be practical if these other forms are released (freed) when closing, not hidden</strike> (edited to reflect Rob's comment):

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  SaveHandler: TCloseQueryEvent;
begin
  for i := 0 to Screen.Formcount - 1 do
    if Screen.Forms[i] <> Self then begin
      SaveHandler := Screen.Forms[i].OnCloseQuery;
      Screen.Forms[i].OnCloseQuery := nil;
      Screen.Forms[i].Close;
      Screen.Forms[i].OnCloseQuery := SaveHandler;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: That's a useful, practical answer, thanks, but it does involve me going through every single OnCloseQuery event of every form - something I'd like to avoid. 
Can't I just release/free/destroy/close the form in such a way that the OnCloseQuery event is never used?

Comment: Re: Your alternative solution:
That's looking good!... It's interesting that I almost kinda thought of it now that I responded to you, and I've been playing with this problem for about 5 hours now! This is why "paired programming" works: people think better when interacting with others. 
Let me give this a go and get back to you, it may be exactly what I need

Comment: So far that's working great, thank you!!!
Like you say, the Form has to be freed after, and this application has been written as such, so it should work well.
Based on my Googling, I'm sure this solution will also be useful to others in the future.
Thanks again :D

Comment: @Richard - You're welcome! I hope I didn't offended you querying your design. :)

Comment: The second suggestion, to detach the event handler, could be practical even when the form isn't being freed. You just have to re-attach the event handler after you call `Close`. Even when the close action is `caFree`, that's safe because the form won't actually be freed immediately. It won't get freed until the program gets around to handing the `cm_Release` message, and we already know the program doesn't do that because `Screen.FormCount` isn't changing during the loop.

Comment: Very nice, Rob . Thanks for that!

Comment: @RobKennedy Problem. Despite detaching the OnCloseQuery event handler and re-attaching it later as per the updated answer, it still gets executed...

Comment: Note that the detach handler approach DOES NOT work for modal Forms shown with `ShowModal()`.  Calling `Close()` on a modal Form simply sets the Form's `ModalResult` property (to `mrCancel`), the `OnClose...` events are not triggered until execution flow returns to the message loop inside of `ShowModal()`, by which time the `OnClose...` handlers have already been re-assigned.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i := 1 to Screen.Formcount - 1 do
  Screen.Forms[i].close;
```

Initial the value i with 1, not 0.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? Especially explain why to start with 1.

Comment: @UwePlonus I guess that will close all forms but the main form, which is Screen.Forms[0]. If you close the man form the program terminates which is not what you want. On the other hand, this does not answer the question because it still calls the OnCloseQuery events.

Comment: the first window is main form, the value index is 0, the second form is 1, the third is 2 ...